# 'assigns' method not found in rspec capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have the following code in my controller:

```
private
def remaining_words
    @remaining_words = Vocab.all.where.not(id: session[:vocab_already_asked])
    @questions_remaining = @remaining_words.length - 4
    @quiz_words = @remaining_words.shuffle.take(4)
```

And here is my test:

```
feature 'Quiz functionality'   do
  scenario "gets 100% questions right in quiz" do
    visit(root_path)
    visit(start_quiz_path)

    assigns(:questions_remaining).length.to_i.times do
      orig_value = find('#orig', visible: false).value
      choose(option: orig_value)
      click_on('Submit')
      expect(page).to have_content('You got it right!')
      expect(page).not_to have_content('Sorry, wrong answer!')
    end

    expect(page).to have_content("Your score is 27/27")
    save_and_open_page
  end
end
```

I get the error message when I run the test:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assigns' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::QuizFunctionality:0x007f8f2de3f2b0>
     # ./spec/features/quizzes_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've also tried using controller.instance_variable_get(:remaining_words) and get this error message

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::QuizFunctionality:0x007fc4b99251a0>
```

Am I missing something in setting up the test? Should I be using describe instead of feature to enable the assign method?

Answer (score 2):

`assigns` was solely available in controller tests - it was depreciated in Rails 5.

> Testing what instance variables are set by your controller is a bad
>   idea. That's grossly overstepping the boundaries of what the test
>   should know about. You can test what cookies are set, what HTTP code
>   is returned, how the view looks, or what mutations happened to the DB,
>   but testing the innards of the controller is just not a good idea.
>   - David Heinemeier Hansson

In RSpec controller specs wrap the deprecated `ActionController::TestCase`.

A controller spec is identified by having the `type: :controller` metadata.

```
RSpec.describe ThingsController, type: :controller do
  # ...
  describe "GET #index" do
  end
end
```

If you have set `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` in `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` RSpec will infer that any spec in `spec/controllers` has `type: :controller`.

You should avoid controller specs for new applications in favor of request and feature specs. One of the main problems with controller specs besides the violation of encapsulation is that the entire request phase is stubbed, the request does not actually go through rack or the routes which can mask routing errors and means that Rack middleware like Warden (used by Devise) or sessions must be stubbed.

If you have a legacy application you can reintroduce `assigns` with a [gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing). If you are just learning RSpec you should select more up to date tutorials.

> Feature specs are high-level tests meant to exercise slices of
>   functionality through an application. They should drive the
>   application only via its external interface, usually web pages.
>   https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/feature-specs

Use feature specs for high level tests centered on the user story. Use `RSpec.feature "New Cool Feature"` to write a feature spec.

> Request specs provide a thin wrapper around Rails' integration tests,
>   and aredesigned to drive behavior through the full stack, including
>   routing (provided by Rails) and without stubbing (that's up to you).
>   https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/request-specs/request-spec

Use `RSpec.describe "Some resource", type: :request` to write a feature spec.

Request specs are invaluable for testing API' or when you just need fast tests that ensure that the correct mutations happened to the DB or that the correct http responses are sent.

See:

- https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950

Comment: The fact that RSpec still generates controller specs is just a question of rspec-rails lagging quite a bit behind the state of the art.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing feature specs/integration tests which don't have access to the controller/controller instance variables. They are meant to be more of a black box test executed from the users perspective.  When setting up the data for the test you should know how many questions need to be asked and then either hardcode that in your test, or, better yet, detect based on the page contents whether there are more questions to answer (just like a user would have to).

Comment: I see. The number of questions are currently hardcoded in, I thought it should be dynamically detected to make it more robust. I'll leave it hardcoded then.